# How did 'man's time on earth' semantically shift to mean the 'earth' itself?

Tags: etymology, proto-germanic

John McWhorter [PhD Linguistics (Stanford)](https://americanstudies.columbia.edu/people/john-h-mcwhorter).  [*Words on the Move* (2016)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1627794719). p. 190 Bottom.

> World began as *wer-eld*, where *wer*

p. 191 Top

> was that "man" word and *eld* meant "old," as in age. *Wer-eld* meant 'man's age," as in "the age of man," as in **man's time on earth [mine]**. Gradually, via implication, it came to mean the earth itself: hence, today's *world*.

How exactly did “man’s time on earth” shift to signify “earth itself”? This feels unnatural; humans are obviously mortal in the short run, but the earth feels (spuriously) immortal, though [Proto-Germanic speakers](https://www.etymonline.com/word/world) wouldn't have known  [20th-century theories on the fate of the universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimate_fate_of_the_universe#Theories_about_the_end_of_the_universe)).

So why refer to something spuriously immortal (earth), by something mortal (man)?

Comment: Belongs on ELU.

Comment: This life, human time in this world → this world, this reality (in opposition to the afterlife / other side).

Comment: @curiousdannii recurringly argues that most etymology is out of scope and English specific (notwithstanding that this is a change in Proto-Germanic and not English). And I'll continue to argue that instances of semantic change are in scope.

Comment: @NickNicholas Doesn't matter when in history the change occurred, as it is a single arbitrary non-systematic change you can't do linguistic analysis on it. It's an etymology question and belongs on a language site.

Comment: See C.S. Lewis, *Studies in Words*, chapter on "world" for a very thorough answer to this question.

Comment: When you can read German, look at 'Welt' in Grimm, *Deutsches Wörterbuch* here: http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GW16669#XGW16669

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually think the more interesting meaning shift is from "era" to "habitat". (This is of course a reprise of the perennial Lakoffian metaphor TIME IS SPACE.) Ancient Greek usage of *aeon* seems to have undergone a similar shift, in philosophy (Plato: the eternal world of ideas); Christianity and Gnosticism (this age = the "mortal", physical universe; the next age = "heaven", the divine universe, by extension of Plato).

But that cosmology appears to underlie *were-eld* as well. In a Platonist, Christian, and for all I know Odinist world-view, the physical world is not immortal at all: immortality is the exclusive preserve of the Gods, who are outside of this world. The guys who came up with [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ragnarök](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ragnar%C3%B6k) had such a world-view, after all.

Comment: While you raise some interesting parallels, I don't see anything that actually answers the question here.

Comment: Huh.  "How exactly did “man’s time on earth” shift to signify “earth itself”?" Addressed in first para, TIME IS SPACE. "So why refer to something spuriously immortal (earth), by something mortal (man)?" Addressed in second para, the Earth was not regarded as immortal.

Comment: Are you suggesting it's a calque? If so do you have any references?

Comment: No, I am not. I am suggesting that the cultural view of the physical world as impermanent was common to Germanic, Hellenic, Christian, and Gnostic religion; no calque is needed from _aeon_ to _wereld_ (and indeed, they are distinct: _aeon_ is "age" in general, not "human-age", and is applied both to this world and the Next.)

Comment: Right, as I said, interesting parallels, but not an answer to the specific etymology of "earth."

Comment: @NickNicholas. If it is a calque, then on saeculum "time, era", then "this transitory time" as opposed to aeternum.

Comment: Wouldn't this rather be an example of SPACE IS TIME?